# Animation Android

Tags: android, xml

I want create a splash screen, So i using animation. Now i want Anim scroll from left to mid ( change % become center_vertical or center_horizontal ).
**Sorry ! I speak English is not good.**

Code xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-220%" android:toXDelta="70%"<!--I want change 70% -> center_vertical-->
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="1200"/>
</set>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the animation to place the View in the center of the Parent View, horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Here... I have two text : text one scroll from left to middle and text two scroll from right to middle.I want animation android:toXDelta="70%", if can change 70% become center_vertical. Because when i test on real device position of text different position on emulator

Comment: Ok, I understand. Did you tried with android:toXDelta="0%"? It makes the animation stop right where the View is placed on the layout. If the View has android:layout_centerHorizontal="true", for example, the animation will stop in the center of the screen.

Comment: :) Oke @joao2fast4u you can change comment become a answer and i vote for you :D. Thank you very much !

Comment: You are welcome. I already added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try with android:toXDelta="0%", it will make the animation stop right where the `View` is placed on the layout by default. For example, if the `View` has `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` attribute in layout, the animation will stop in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void desaparecer(final LinearLayout parent, View hijo, int espaciofinal) {

    parent.removeView(hijo);

    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)parent.getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params.height, espaciofinal);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator)
        {
            params.height= (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            parent.getChildAt(0).requestLayout();
        }
    });
    animator.setDuration(300);
    animator.start();

}
```

This are my code, and work... well, a little bad.

i'm searching the way to don't start above 0pd, because the idea it's that start respect the original height.

but if like you, you can use it

Comment: Please write where in the code you have the problem and what is your expected in-/output?!